# My CollectionView Cell Hide

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I am use ScrollView . In my scroll view there is Collection View. My collection view last 3 element hide inside white space. On scrolling ScrollView they not show.They Shown on scrolling CollectionView. I want to show shown all Collection Cell On Scroll ScrollView. Not Scrolling CollectionView.

```
-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:
(UICollectionView *)collectionView {

    return 1; // The number of sections we want
}
-(NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
    numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    return 5; // the number of cells we want
}

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionViewd
                  cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    CollectionCell* cell =
    [collectionViewd dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"collectionView2CellIdentifier"
                                               forIndexPath:indexPath]; // Create the cell from the storyboard cell

    cell.layer.cornerRadius = 4;
    cell.layer.borderWidth = 1;
    cell.layer.borderColor = [UIColor grayColor].CGColor;

    cell.yellow.layer.cornerRadius=4;
    cell.red.layer.cornerRadius=4;


    cell.title.text =[titleArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.date.text =[dateArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.incomeText.text =[netIncomeArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.expenseText.text =[netExpenseArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
     cell.saving.text =[savingArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.expensePecentageText.text =[expensePercentage objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.savingPercentage.text =[netProfitPercentage objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return cell; // Return the cell
}

- (CGFloat)collectionView:(UICollectionView *) collectionView
                   layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *) collectionViewLayout
minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger) section {
    return 2.0;
}


- (UIEdgeInsets)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout insetForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section
{
    return UIEdgeInsetsMake(2, 2, 2, 2);
}
- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    return CGSizeMake(155, 158);

}
    [scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(0, expenseButton.frame.origin.y+expenseButton.frame.size.height+collection.frame.size.height+16)];
```

Comment: try to set the scrollview height as collection view height.

Comment: @Sohil I am setting  [scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(0, expenseButton.frame.origin.y+expenseButton.frame.size.height+collection.frame.size.height+16)];

Comment: when you set the setContentSize ? after loading the collection or before

Comment: Before on view did load

Comment: please change it after loading the collection view setContentSize of scrollview

Answer (score 1):

First of all count the height of collectionview By :

For Example

titleArray.count * 160 (158px cell height + 2px cell space)

Then assign this height to collectionview frame

also assign this to scrollview content size height.

This will surely do the trick for you.

Comment: This will not accepts because in Iphone 6 there are two cell on one row, In one iPhone 5 there is single row